# Right hand side also gets assigned

Tags: list, common-lisp, variable-assignment

Directly stating the problem; I assign the 'temp' as *TEMP* in the let statement. When I do so, *TEMP* gets assigned exactly what 'temp' had been assigned at each iteration. And I am ending up pushing the same value of 'temp's at the end. Don't have a clue why, do you guys have any idea about how things go wrong in here?

```
(defparameter *TEMP* `((key value)(key2 value2)(key3 x))
(defparameter *SYNS* NIL)
(defparameter *PUSH-HERE* NIL)

(dolist (i *matrix*)
  (dolist (j i)
    (if  (equal 'keyword (first j)) 
        (foo (second j))))       ;fills *SYNS*
  (let ((temp *TEMP*))
    ;(print *TEMP*) prints temps last assigned value?
    (set-key temp (get-key i))   ;gets key's value
    (set-key2 temp (get-key2 i)) ;gets key2's value    
    (loop while (not (equal 0 (length *SYNS*)))
          do (set-key3 temp (pop *syns*))
          (push temp *PUSH-HERE*))))
```

Resulting value becomes like this;

```
 ((key last-assigned-value)(key2 last-assigned-value)(key3 last-assigned-value)
 (key last-assigned-value)(key2 last-assigned-value)(key3 last-assigned-value)
 (key last-assigned-value)(key2 last-assigned-value)(key3 last-assigned-value))
```

instead of;

```
((key first-assigned-value)(key2 first-assigned-value)(key3 first-assigned-value)
 (key second-assigned-value)(key2 second-assigned-value)(key3 second-assigned-value)
 (key last-assigned-value)(key2 last-assigned-value)(key3 last-assigned-value))
```

I have tried printing, and just before push line, temp is printed as I want, but after the whole iteration is completed, I got the unintentional list I put above.

Comment: What is `*matrix*`?

Comment: It's difficult to guess what your code does when it is not a complete listing.

Comment: *matrix* is a collection of entries like temp. I am trying to compose new values in the foo function and by rplacd function I am force setting those new values to a template, illustrated here as *temp*, then appending them to the *matrix*. The entire code is in github.com/karavana/cogs/blob/dev/core/funcs_usingLoad.lisp

Comment: Btw., there are tabs in the file, which make it hard to read online.

Comment: You mean the github code? Yes, needs an editing but thats the least of my problems for now..

Comment: But when I would look at it, then the indentation is basically not usable as it is now. If you want help, you might provide better indented code. ;-) It's then the same problem on Stackoverflow, if you copy the code. That's why I had edited your question code.

Comment: Yes I see, sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding the address of `*temp*` to `temp`. I assume `set-key` updates `temp` as with `rplaca` or `(setf (car place) value)`. Thus you are modifying `*temp*` also since it is the same value as `temp`.  Every round you are overwriting *temp* which is the same address you have been pushing to the neew list and thus it results in 3 sub lists of the same since they are the same. This is also in violation of Common Lisp since `*temp*`is quoted literal, and thus constant, data. It might behave differently in different implementations.

Instead of destructive operation you could do non destructive operation that crates a new value, eg. with [`substitute-if`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_sbs_s.htm), then update the binding:

```
(setf temp 
      (substitute-if (cons 'key 'new-value) 
                     (lambda (e) (eq e 'key)) 
                     temp
                     :key #'car))
```

If you still want mutation you can get away with it by using [`copy-alist`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_cp_ali.htm#copy-alist):

```
(let ((temp (copy-alist *temp*)))
  ...)
```

Comment: Yes I am using replacd to change the values of *temp* in the setter functions. I provided a link to my code in the comments section of the question. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @Karavana I've looked at it and it confirmed my suspicion that both of my suggestions will work.

Answer (score 2):

A variable is a box which contains a value. A cons cell (for example the start of the list you put in `*temp*`) is a place in memory with some pointers. When you do `(let ((temp *temp*)) ...`, you are making the variable `temp` point to the same bit of memory as `*temp*`, so when you are modifying that data structure, you are modifying the very same memory pointed to by `*temp*`.

One way to fix your code is to try to see how lisp programs are normally written and make your code more like that, instead of applying your knowledge of how to write C programs to a language with very different semantics (in particular, Common Lisp does not have value semantics like C). One improvement would be to construct the data you want instead of poking at it with chopsticks (ie `set-key` and friends).
I can’t execute your code because you have failed to provide a minimum executable example but you can construct one row from your desired output by doing something like:

```
`((key ,what-you-want-for-first-value)
  (key2 ,second-value)
  (key3 ,third))
```

This will make a new object in fresh memory.

Comment: I have given a link to my code in the comments section. You would need to load a file like I do to from a path, I can provide that as well if needed.

Answer (score 1):

> I assign the 'temp' as *TEMP* in the let statement. When I do so, *TEMP* gets assigned exactly what 'temp' had been assigned at each iteration

The variable `temp` gets the same value as the variable `*temp*`. The exact same object, if it is a list. `*temp*` does not get a new value.

```
CL-USER 30 > (defvar *temp* '(1 2 3))
*TEMP*

CL-USER 31 > (let ((temp *temp*))
               (eq temp *temp*))
T
```

Comment: I now know how it behaves, then the new question is, what would it be to change the code so that it behaves like I want it to :))